# Magento Proflier help analyzing

Tags: magento-1.9, admin-panel

> In one of my clients Magento setup 1.9.2 it is taking too long like
>   5-7 minutes. I have enabled the code profiler to debug it.
>
> The result I am getting is like for example:

[image]

> Now my question is I believe that the time shown against Mage in Sr.2
>   is 5.7526 seconds. but its really taking a total time around 7-8
>   minutes. what should I look for to address t?e issue. Thanks.

Comment: this is not full screenshot.  you need to look for lines with time longer than seconds

Comment: yes it is not full spreadsheet, but other eateries timing is much lesser actually.